# How to set multiple hosts of istio DestionationRule?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

There is DestinationRule like below

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-ratings
spec:
  host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: LEAST_REQUEST
```

We may want to get traffic from `ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local` as well as rating.custom.domain.
But we can't set multiple host because `spec.host` is not list or dict, just string.

Answer (score 0):

Destination Rules apply the traffic setting by overriding the settings specified at the service level using the service name as the reference.
This is why you can have only one host per each DR.

You will need to create a DR per each host that you want to configure.